# Embed Google docs in GitLab markdown file

Tags: google-sheets, gitlab, markdown, google-docs

I want to embed Google docs - and possibly Google sheets - in a GitLab markdown file.
[GitLab's markdown guide](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/#embed-documents) lists the following steps to do this:

- open your Google document
- click *File* -> *Publish to the web*
- choose *Embed*
- click on *Publish* and copy the `<iframe>`
- go to your markdown file and wrap the iframe into a `<figure>` tag with the responsive `video_container` class like in this example:

```html
<figure class="video_container">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jAnvYpRmNu8BISIrkYGTLolOTmlCoKLbuHVWzCXJSY4/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
</figure>
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me. Instead of the embedded document I only see whitespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[this guide](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/) or [this one](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/07/19/markdown-kramdown-tips-and-tricks/) are refering to [Kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/) which is a Markdown converter used by https://about.gitlab.com:

> For about.GitLab.com we use kramdown, which is an advanced Markdown
>   engine with a lot of interesting features that most of the other
>   engines don't have, such as inline attribute lists (IALs), which
>   enable easy styling beyond the standard Markdown options.

This guide was dedicated mainly for building static website by rendering markdown using kramdown (essentially for writing blog post) :

> This guide has been made to make it easier for everyone to use
>   kramdown features and save a lot of time writing content for
>   about.GitLab.com, including handbook pages, website pages, blog posts
>   and everything else within the project www-GitLab-com.

Gitlab.com, Gitlab CE and Gitlab EE uses Github Flavored Markdown, an extension of common mark :

> In most of GitLab text areas you'll find markdown support. Not all of
>   them run with kramdown, so the markup will not behave equally
>   "GitLabwide". For GitLab.com, GitLab CE and GitLab EE text areas, the
>   markdown engine is currently CommonMarker. Here you can find the
>   markdown style guide for them.

If you are interesting in rendering Markdown in Gitlab file (eg Readme, etc...), the Markdown guide is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html

Embedding Google sheet in GitLab Flavored Markdown is not possible, unless you want to just include a picture of it or if you want to [copy/paste the spreadsheet content to markdown format](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#copy-from-spreadsheet-and-paste-in-markdown)

Comment: What a pity! Thank you so much, though, Bertrand! I wasn't aware that GitLab uses several different markdown engines. That explains a lot :D